# error in iOS calculator decimal point

Tags: ios, calculator

I built an iOS calculator and I put in a decimal function and whenever I press the decimal button a decimal will be inserted then when i push another number the decimal disappears. I don't know if i need to put code in for the decimal in every number or what. If someone could give me specific instructions it would help me so much.

here is the code for the decimal in .m

```
- (IBAction)Decimal:(id)sender
{
    NSRange range = [self->Screen.text rangeOfString:@"."];
    if (range.location ==NSNotFound){
        self->Screen.text = [ self->Screen.text stringByAppendingString:@"."];
    }


}
```

and here is .h

```
-(IBAction)Decimal:(id)sender;
```

as an example here is one of the number buttons

```
-(IBAction)Number1:(id)sender{

    SelectNumber = SelectNumber * 10;
    SelectNumber = SelectNumber + 1;
    Screen.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", SelectNumber];
```

**update**

I fixed some of the errors on my own but am stuck on this one. when I launch the app the screen defaults to zero. whenever I enter any number the zero is supposed to be replaced by the number I select, but it doesn't get replaced. I just don't know exactly what code would point to that issue.

Comment: Could you also post whatever code is triggered when you type your numbers? Like, are you using any of the UITextField delegate methods? Because the problem doesn't have anything to do with your Decimal: method if the problem occurs when its not being triggered...

Comment: What's SelectNumber?

Comment: I saw you selected then deselected my answer. Still need help?

Comment: sorry I have been away a lot recently and i was dealing with other technicalities with the app so thank you so so much for your help

Comment: OK, no worries :) Hope the app making's progressing well

Comment: These two lines are suspicious: `SelectNumber = SelectNumber * 10;` `SelectNumber = SelectNumber + 1;`. If you want the number you append to be "1" SelectNumber should simply equal 1

Comment: Ok so I am still having trouble with the decimal it is probably a pretty simple fix but I just cant figure it out. The decimal works and will stay there and not be replaced by another number like I was having trouble with before, but whenever I press a number then press another number it will repeat the last number I pressed before displaying the new number. For example I press 1 then I press 2 the screen will show 0112 and say I press 6 the screen will now show 011226. It just has to do with the last line of code in the number function. Sorry if this is too confusing.

Comment: I'd recommend adding an update under your question containing your current code.

Comment: How do I highlight my code in a comment?

Comment: By putting it between two of these symbols: `

Comment: But I meant for you to add the code in your question not a comment... Just add it below your current question as an update.

Comment: did you see the update?

Comment: OK, I see it... I may not have time to look it over until tomorrow though...

Comment: I looked it over and I don't understand your new question at all...

Comment: here is an update explaining it better. If it is still unclear would it be easier if I just gave you my whole .m file? sorry I am being such an inconvenience.

Comment: Yeah it's still very unclear what you're  trying to ask exactly. I don't think seeing your whole .m will help until you've made the exact question you're asking clearer.

Comment: That should hopefully be clear enough

Comment: Oh OK. That second question is completely different from the first and probably belongs in an entire new post, but I'd recommend implementing a text field delegate method like `shouldChangeCharactersInRange:` or `textFieldDidBeginEditing:` depending on your exact desired behavior then deleting the leading 0 upon user entry.

Comment: Oh ok. I think I understand how it would work but how exactly could I do it in order to make the number get deleted upon the user entering it?

Comment: Like I said, you should post a new question because it's unrelated to your original question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that by using this sort of line in your number methods:

```
Screen.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", SelectNumber];
```

You're setting the entirety of `Screen` (which I'm assuming is a text field or text view of sorts) to contain `SelectNumber`, which as you say in your comment, is the number selected. Because of this, everything else will be overwritten.

As long as you're not allowing the user to insert text in the middle of your text field/view, you can correct the problem by using the same sort of logic you use in `Decimal:` and append `SelectNumber` to the end. Change:

```
Screen.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", SelectNumber];
```

to:

```
Screen.text = [Screen.text stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", SelectNumber]];
```